# Python3-pip install: http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 gcc-7 amd64 7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04 Unreachable

Tags: python, ubuntu-18.04, apt

i'm trying to install python3-pip with apt, but it seems that `http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 gcc-7 amd64 7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04` is unreachable
I have already tried `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade`

```
ansible@asl-master:/etc/apt$ sudo apt-get install python3-pip
Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
Construction de l'arbre des dépendances
Lecture des informations d'état... Fait
Les paquets supplémentaires suivants seront installés :
  binutils binutils-x86-64-linux-gnu build-essential cpp cpp-7 dh-python dpkg-dev fakeroot g++ g++-7 gcc gcc-7 libalgorithm-diff-perl libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl
  libalgorithm-merge-perl libasan4 libatomic1 libbinutils libc-dev-bin libc6-dev libcilkrts5 libdpkg-perl libexpat1-dev libfakeroot libfile-fcntllock-perl libgcc-7-dev libgomp1
  libitm1 liblsan0 libmpx2 libpython3-dev libpython3.6-dev libquadmath0 libstdc++-7-dev libtsan0 libubsan0 linux-libc-dev make manpages-dev python-pip-whl python3-crypto
  python3-dev python3-keyring python3-keyrings.alt python3-secretstorage python3-wheel python3-xdg python3.6-dev
Paquets suggérés :
  binutils-doc cpp-doc gcc-7-locales debian-keyring g++-multilib g++-7-multilib gcc-7-doc libstdc++6-7-dbg gcc-multilib autoconf automake libtool flex bison gdb gcc-doc
  gcc-7-multilib libgcc1-dbg libgomp1-dbg libitm1-dbg libatomic1-dbg libasan4-dbg liblsan0-dbg libtsan0-dbg libubsan0-dbg libcilkrts5-dbg libmpx2-dbg libquadmath0-dbg glibc-doc
  bzr libstdc++-7-doc make-doc python-crypto-doc gnome-keyring libkf5wallet-bin gir1.2-gnomekeyring-1.0 python-secretstorage-doc
Les NOUVEAUX paquets suivants seront installés :
  binutils binutils-x86-64-linux-gnu build-essential cpp cpp-7 dh-python dpkg-dev fakeroot g++ g++-7 gcc gcc-7 libalgorithm-diff-perl libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl
  libalgorithm-merge-perl libasan4 libatomic1 libbinutils libc-dev-bin libc6-dev libcilkrts5 libdpkg-perl libexpat1-dev libfakeroot libfile-fcntllock-perl libgcc-7-dev libgomp1
  libitm1 liblsan0 libmpx2 libpython3-dev libpython3.6-dev libquadmath0 libstdc++-7-dev libtsan0 libubsan0 linux-libc-dev make manpages-dev python-pip-whl python3-crypto
  python3-dev python3-keyring python3-keyrings.alt python3-pip python3-secretstorage python3-wheel python3-xdg python3.6-dev
0 mis à jour, 49 nouvellement installés, 0 à enlever et 0 non mis à jour.
Il est nécessaire de prendre 7 455 ko/83,9 Mo dans les archives.
Après cette opération, 241 Mo d'espace disque supplémentaires seront utilisés.
Souhaitez-vous continuer ? [O/n] o
Réception de:1 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 gcc-7 amd64 7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04 [7 455 kB]
Réception de:1 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 gcc-7 amd64 7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04 [7 455 kB]
Réception de:1 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 gcc-7 amd64 7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04 [7 455 kB]
Réception de:1 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 gcc-7 amd64 7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04 [7 455 kB]
Réception de:1 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 gcc-7 amd64 7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04 [7 455 kB]
Réception de:1 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 gcc-7 amd64 7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04 [7 455 kB]
Réception de:1 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 gcc-7 amd64 7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04 [7 455 kB]
Réception de:1 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 gcc-7 amd64 7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04 [7 455 kB]
```

This is my sources.list:

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 18.04 LTS _Bionic Beaver_ - Release amd64 (20180426)]/ bionic main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
```

Comment: I don't know what happened with you. But you can download pip directly from https://pypi.org/project/pip/ and install it by `python setup.py install`

Comment: Maybe try to use global cdn for the ubuntu package:

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main universe 
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates main universe

Comment: I tried your solution @Yang HG and it works ! thanks for the quick reply

Answer (score -1):

If the website is unreachable, try fixing the broken packages with:

```
$ sudo apt -f install
```

Afterwards, finish the fix with:

```
$ sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

Now, you should be able to run:

```
$ sudo apt install python3-pip
```

Best of luck.